# convert double values in decimal (fraction) values java

Tags: java, double, decimalformat

I have below code:

```
Double a = new Double((123456798/1000000)); //123456798 this value comes from client side as a `int`
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.###");            
log.info("a :"+a+" df "+df.format(a.doubleValue()));
```

output:

```
a :123.0 df 123
//i want output like this, a :123.xxx fd 123.xxx
```

please help

**UPDATE:**

123456798 this value comes from client side as a `int` so i cant do it as 123456798.0 (or something)

Comment: Just because you receive the value as an `int` doesn't mean you can't assign it to a `double` variable... (Why are you creating a `Double` at all? I see no need to use the wrapper type here...)

Comment: i have value in Rupees currency (`123456798`) so i take it as a `int` and i have convert rupees to million so that i have divided it `1000000`

Comment: @JonSkeet please see above comment.

Comment: So (123456798*1.0)/1000000 will give you answer in factions.

Comment: None of your comments address the questions asked by my comment. Also, you should consider using BigDecimal instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet i have value in Rupees currency (`123456798`) so i take it as a `int` and i have to convert rupees to million so that i have divided it `1000000`

Comment: @JonSkeet if i use `double dd = 123456798/1000000` i am getting same output.

Comment: @mohsinazeem: I didn't suggest that, did I? I suggested taking the `int` value you're provided, and storing *that* in a `double` variable: `double x = valueReceivedFromElsewhere; double y = x / 1000000;`. That's effectively the same as casting, of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are master man! thanks for this suggestion, now i am using it (Y).

Answer (score 3):

`123456798` and `1000000` are `int` literals, so dividing them will use integer arithmetic, and yield `123`.
Instead, you could use floating point literals in order to use floating point arithmetic:

```
Double a = new Double((123456798.0/1000000.0));
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.###");            
log.info("a :"+a+" df "+df.format(a.doubleValue()));
```

Comment: `double a = 123456798.0/1000000.0;` would be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Any one value in the division should be float or double.

```
Double a = new Double((123456798.0/1000000));
```

or

```
Double a = new Double((123456798/1000000.0));
```

if you are getting these values in variables, then `multiply it with 1.0`

like

```
Double a = new Double((variable*1.0/1000000));
```

Comment: Why multiply by 1.0 rather than just casting to `double`? And why continue the OP's pointless use of `Double`? And why the double parentheses? Basically this would be better as: `double a = variable / 1000000.0;` or if you really want, `double a = ((double) variable) / 1000000;`

Comment: @JonSkeet you replied late that's why i voted this answer, and i used `1.0`, but now i am using your suggestion!! thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Put it like that

```
Double a = new Double((123456798.0/1000000.0)); // <- note ".0"
```

the reason of the misbehavior is the *integer division*:

```
  123456798/1000000
```

is the *integer* value, while

```
  123456798.0/1000000.0
```

is the *floating point* one (double)

Answer (score 1):

```
Double a = new Double((123456798/1000000));
```

You are doing integer division here. Make one of the constants a `double`, so that floating-point division is done. Also, why are you using `Double`? It's better to use the primitive type `double`.

```
double a = 123456798.0 / 1000000;
```

Or simply, since they are constants:

```
double a = 123.456789;
```

Answer (score 0):

You perform an integer division, thats why `a` is incorrect:

```
Double a = new Double(123456798.0/1000000);
```